# html5 canvas image movement issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

[image]

The picture is drawn using:

```
ctx.drawImage(this.img, renderPositionX, renderPositionY, renderSizeX, renderSizeY);
```

When I slowly move the picture at a speed of 0.005 pixels per frame, I begin to observe how the image is compressed and stretched. As if each pixel is periodically stretched to the next pixel.

Tried: ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true; But it only enables smoothing of picture itself, not how it is moved.
Also tried to round size and position (renderPositionX, renderPositionY, renderSizeX, renderSizeY).

How can I fix this? What is it all about?

Comment: Why are you trying to move sub-pixel? As it cannot be rendered. Consider frame skipping to the next pixel. For example if you want to move 0.5px per second. move 1px every 2secs. I realize this might cause issues if you are tracking unlocked frame rate. In which case just track a pixel increment var on each frame. Are you already doing a requestAnimationFrame() ?

Comment: @Bibberty yes, i am already using requestanimationframe. As i described in post, i tried rounding to integer render position and render size of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem too, and I found the best fix was to use

```
context.drawImage(src, Math.round(xPos), Math.round(yPos));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Image? Maybe you mean context.drawImage instead?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that, I'm used to an ease of access function I made that allows me to use Image(ctx.drawImage Paramaters) so that I can have to type in ctx.draw every time. I fixed the problem. :P

Comment: great. This helps me a lot.